# Find ID in a sheet that is common to another sheet in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks that contains a common project ID in two different sheets . I created  a code which allows the programme to search for a unique ID in one sheet, retrieve information from that row , pertaining to that id , then pasting to the row of that corresponding project ID, to another sheet in another workbook. This code works but only works under the assumption of which both the both lists are in exactly the same order , when in actual fact they are jumbled up. So i need help to incorporate find feature in the code, which finds the project ID in one workbook sheet , retrieve the row information and paste it another workbook sheet.

```
Sub AAA()

'If Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value Then
'Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
Dim a As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim target As Worksheet
    Dim cellFound As Range



    Set target = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set source = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastrow = source.Range("A" & target.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcol = target.Cells(2, target.Columns.Count).Column

    target.Activate

'For a = 2 To 50
For Each cell In target.Range("A2:A500")
        ' Try to find this value in the source sheet

        Set cellFound = source.Range("A:A").Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then

            cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Copy
            cellFound.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


     'If source.Range("A" & a).Value = target.Range("A" & a).Value Then
     'target.Range("C" & a).Select
     'Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0)).Copy
     'source.Range("B" & a).PasteSpecial
     Else
     Exit Sub


     End If

Next



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like below should match them no matter what order the ID is in, you have to use two arrays. It copies column B assuming ID is in column A, please continue to add for however many columns you want copying. See below and try on your own code. UNTESTED.

```
Dim fpath As String
Dim owb As Workbook



fpath = "change to the location of workbook you want to paste to"


Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath) 'opens workbook

Dim Master As Worksheet 'your current book
Dim Slave As Worksheet 'one your pasting too

'please verify if the master and slave are correct here
Set Slave = owb.Worksheets("name of sheet in one your pasting too")
Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("name of sheet in book you are in")

For i = 1 To 1000 '(the slave sheet)
For j = 1 To 1000 '(the master sheet)

If Master.Cells(j, 1).Value = "" Then ExitFor   


   If Master.Cells(j, 1).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 1).Value Then 'assuming both Id's are in column A
       Slave.Cells(i, 2).Value = Master.Cells(j, 2).Value 'this will copy column B, continue to add for each column you want copying e.g. add another with "3" and "4" etc.

  End If
End If

Next
Next


MsgBox ("Data Transfer Successful")
```